# Return to Windows from Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, 18.04, windows, hard-drive, bios

I have no experience at Ubuntu or any other Linux OS. Yesterday I tried to upgrade my Windows 7 to Windows 10 and some problems occurred. I couldn't install Windows 10 and I even lost my Windows 7 data. I figured out the problem was my Windows 10 .iso file. I hadn't any access to another computer and I had only Ubuntu DVD, so I decided to install Ubuntu 18.04. After I installed Ubuntu I made a Windows 10 installer USB.

Then the problems began. I connected the USB and nothing happened, also After I installed Ubuntu, I lost access to regular blue screen BIOS settings. When I see the "Click F2 for BIOS" option, it doesn't matter how fast I click or how many times I click, the PC automatically boots Ubuntu. I started to think how to solve my problem and I found a stupid idea. I have few hard drives at my house, so I thought if I change the hard drive of the notebook, I could install a new Windows to  a new hard drive.

When I changed the hard drive, my Samsung NP300e5c notebook keeps resetting every second. I thought the hard drive may be broken, so I tried 5 different hard drives, but the result was same for all of them. The only hard drive that let me boot the notebook is the one on which Ubuntu is installed.

I gave up trying, and I went to several computer service centers at my district. Each one of them gave advice that contradicted the others and said I had a different (expensive) problem. The first one said: "You deleted your BIOS, I can repair it, but it will cost about $100. The second one said: "It's a common issue, your motherboard is broken. We have to change your motherboard and it will cost maybe $150+." The third one said: "I can't fix this." Someone even said that the CPU is toast. If the CPU is toast, how is it possible that I can run Ubuntu on a notebook with this CPU in it?

I couldn't find someone who could fix this or help me.

I just want to return back to Windows. I'm not a pro PC user. I'm a basic man with basic interests. I searched this BIOS issue at forums, etc., but all the answers are different from each other, and I couldn't find someone who fixed this issue. My last hope is here. *How can I remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?*

My notebook is Samsung NP300e5c. When I run `lspci -v` I get the following results:

```
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])

Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NP300E5C series laptop
Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 25
I/O ports at 3088 [size=8]
I/O ports at 3094 [size=4]
I/O ports at 3080 [size=8]
I/O ports at 3090 [size=4]
I/O ports at 3060 [size=32]
Memory at 90608000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: ahci
Kernel modules: ahci
```

When I try to find the hard drive at the Windows installer screen (see below screenshot), it doesn't see the hard drive either.

[image: Windows installer screen]

Comment: I've been installing Windows and Ubuntu and other Linux distros since primary school and never have I lost access to BIOS/UEFI. All those telling you "BIOS deleted" or the motherboard toasted are trying to rip you off. No, what happens in modern motherboards with UEFI and the fast boot feature enabled is that you have only a very small Windows of time to halt the booting process and access the settings. If it's F2 in your case then spam the key immediately after pressing the power on button, do NOT wait for the "press F2" to appear (also try ESC or DEL). >>>

Comment: thank you for your reply, my device is samsung np300e5c, i tried the click f2 even before the click power button, but still i cant access bios.Do you have any idea why the other hdd wont letme open the notebook and keep resetting ?

Comment: >>> and if your firmware has the option for one-time boot menu you can use just that to boot override and boot from external installation media without opening the full settings. I hope this explains why your question is off-topic, as it has nothing to do with Ubuntu. Your question may eventually be on-topic if you want to know how to burn a Windows 10 installation USB that works in Ubuntu > Short answer: You just use MKUSB.

Comment: I don't know about the other HDD's. Again, your question is off-topic here. I suggest you try at superuser.com which is the generic website for all OSes and computer hardware. AskUbuntu is for Ubuntu questions only.

Comment: ah thanks , sorry about that ill try to find help from there than , thanks again

Answer (score 0):

ext4 is the default filesystem format in Ubuntu 18.04, but Windows is expecting a hard drive that is formatted as NTFS. Otherwise the Windows installer will stop and not continue, because it does not recognize your laptop's ext4 formatted hard drive. To solve this problem boot the laptop from the live DVD/USB that you used to install Ubuntu 18.04. You may need to set the USB flash drive as first in the boot sequence in the BIOS, so your laptop will be able to boot from it. Open the built-in GParted partition editor application, and format the entire hard drive as NTFS.

If this doesn't work then buy a portable hard drive enclosure. They are very cheap, being just a box the same size as a laptop's 2.5" hard drive with a USB port and a USB cable to attach it to another computer. Remove the laptop's hard drive and plug it into the portable hard drive enclosure. Then take the portable hard drive enclosure to another computer and format the hard drive as NTFS. After the hard drive is formatted as NTFS, put it back in its original place in the laptop.

[image: portable hard drive enclosure]
<sup>**portable hard drive enclosure**</sup>

Now your laptop is ready to install Windows. When you boot the Windows 10 installer after formatting the laptop's hard drive as NTFS, the Windows installer will recognize it and the Windows 10 installation will proceed normally.

The error message screen of Windows installer shows that the Windows installer USB boots successfully and starts the Windows installer, but it does not find the hard drive (which possibly is still ext4 formatted).